# OpenCV Watermark keeping aspect ratio not giving same input/output results

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, opencv, watermark

I'm trying to watermark an image for a percentage of the width of the watermarked image, and it is partially working.

This is how the watermark looks like in the web browser and by `imshow()` from opencv:
[image]

As you can see it removed the black border...

In my code:

- `w` stands for watermark
- `wH`, `wW`, `wD` stands for watermark Height, Width and Depth respectively
- `i` stands for image
- `iH`, `iW`, `iD` stands for image Height, Width and Depth respectively
- `nwW` stands for new watermark Width
- `nwH` stands for new watermark Height
- `nwD` stands for new watermark dimensions

Actual code:

```
import cv2
import imutils
import numpy as np

# Reading the watermark
w = cv2.imread('input/watermark.png', cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)

# If not doing this hack the watermark loses the alpha channel
(B, G, R, A) = cv2.split(w)
B = cv2.bitwise_and(B, B, mask=A)
G = cv2.bitwise_and(G, G, mask=A)
R = cv2.bitwise_and(R, R, mask=A)
w = cv2.merge([B, G, R, A])

# Getting the width, height, depth for the watermark
(wH, wW, wD) = w.shape

# Reading the image
i = cv2.imread('input/image1920.png')
# Getting the width, height, depth for the image
(iH, iW, iD) = i.shape
# I've read that I had to add a new dimension (I don't know why)
i = np.dstack([i, np.ones((iH, wW), dtype="uint8") * 255])

# 80% of the image Width should be the new widt for the Watermark
nwW = 80 * int(iW) / 100
# Calculating the ratio
ratio = nwW / iW
# Calculating the new watermakr Height based on the ratio
nwH = wH * ratio
# Tuple with the new watermak dimensions
nwD = (int(nwW), int(nwH))
# Resizing the watermark to its new dimensions
resized_w = cv2.resize(w, nwD)

# Creating an overlay
overlay = np.zeros((iH, iW, 4), dtype="uint8")
overlay[iH - int(nwH) - 10:iH - 10, iW - int(nwW) - 10:iW - 10] = resized_w

# Blending the two images
output = i.copy()
cv2.addWeighted(overlay, 1, output, 1, 0, output)

# Showing the results
cv2.imshow("watermark test", resized_w)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Comment: "# I've read that I had to add a new dimension (I don't know why)" because the watermark is BGRA (with alpha channel) and the image1920.png is BGR (with no alpha channel) so to keep them groovin together, you would create a fourth channel A for your image1920.

Comment: to imread with alpha chsnnel you'll need a special flag

Comment: @Micka I thought that flag was `cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED`

Comment: @AlexanderReynolds That's right, I knew that. But passing wrong parameters to that function made me think that the channel was created for the watermark, a non-sense thing since it is a 24bit png RGBA. I'll edit that when I wake up (7:49am here)